# How can I put this in horizontal inline block?

Tags: html, css

I have this an I want it inline-block but horizontal. Now it is working as inline-block but vertical.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="ondisplay">
            <div class="left-text">
                <p>Newest</p>
            </div>
            <div class="toggle">    
                <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="toggle" name="check" />
                <label for="toggle"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="right-text">
                <p>Most Popular</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.ondisplay {
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also add `inline-block` to children `div's` so that they align in one line and the parent `inline-block` will give the exact children

```css
.ondisplay {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ondisplay div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ondisplay">
  <div class="left-text">
    <p>Newest</p>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="toggle" name="check" />
    <label for="toggle"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="right-text">
    <p>Most Popular</p>
  </div>
</div>
```